# Javascript e AngularJS - Boas práticas para capturar dados de um usuário logado

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Senhores, boa tarde. 
Gostaria de perguntar qual a melhor prática que vocês utilizam para realizar a captura dos dados de um usuário logado numa aplicação web com banco de dados.

Por exemplo: Supondo que eu criei um site onde o usuário se cadastra, realiza o login com seu e-mail e senha, e quando loga é direcionado para uma tela com uma painel com uma série de opções, uma delas é poder alterar suas informações cadastrais. Como devo salvar e capturar esses valores supondo que uso banco de dados MySQL? Session Storage e criptografia?

Meu objetivo de criar um site seguro que garanta a integridade dos dados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem muita coisa a levar em consideração, como é a forma que você faz esse login (você disse que cria uma sessão, seu back-end pode ser Asp.net ou PHP) se é Sessão criada entre a aplicação e servidor ou cookies para autenticação em API. Cada uma é feita de um jeito, pode ficar seguro das duas formas.

Seria interessante primeiro fixar estes conceitos, sugiro que você dê uma lida em:
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-cookies (servidor e cliente)

Eu prefiro criar uma API do meu back-end onde eu tenho minhas regras de negócio e  uma outra API do front-end para me comunicar com  back-end. Assim toda vez que eu for fazer algo no banco eu realizo um [HTTP Request method](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) e autenticando cada operação.

[image: Essa imagem pode lhe ajudar a entender o conceito.]

Comment: Olá Rafael. Eu uso PHP como backend e até o momento tenho usado um banco de dados local para armazenar os dados em tabela.